# Defining controller accessible variables from filters in Grails

Tags: authentication, grails, controller

I'm writing a small webapp in Grails, and to make sure all users are authenticated I'm using the following filter:

```
class LoginFilters {
  static filters = {
    loginCheck(controller:'*', action:'*') {
      before = {
        if (session.user_id) {
          request.user = User.get(session.user_id)
        } else if (!actionName.equals("login")) {
          redirect(controller: "login", action: "login")
          return false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And all controller methods start with reading the user property of the request object:

```
def actionName = {
   def user = request.user
   ...
}
```

The code above works, but I'd rather avoid the duplicate code in the all controller methods. Would it be possible for the filter to bind the user object to a variable named "user" instead of "request.user", that will be accessible from all controllers?

I understand that there might be scoping issues that makes this impossible, but the Grails framework seems to be able to create quite some magic under the hood, so I figured it might be worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the beforeInterceptor in a controller may help:

```
class LoginController {

    def user

    def beforeInterceptor = {
        user = request.user
    }

    def index = { 
        render text:"index: ${user}"        
    }

    def test = {
        render text:"test: ${user}"         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it generally not a good idea insert the user object into the request object every time:

The request lifetime is very short, so you might end up making round trips to caches or even worse to the database on each http-request to retrieve an object, that you might not even need and that get's deleted immideately afterwards. So if you must, better store the whole object in the session instead of just the id.

Generally, I'd suggest you write a `AuthenticationService` with a method `isLoggedIn()` that returns true when the user is authenticated and a method `getLoggedInUser()` that returns this object.

```
class AuthenticationService {
    def transactional = false
    boolean isLoggedIn() { return session.user_id }
    def getLoggedInUser() { return User.get(session.user_id) }
}
```

Then you use the Filter for redirection if not authenticated, and maybe the Interceptor for storing the local reference `user = authenticationService.loggedInUser`. But also I don't think this the best way to go. I suggest you'd create an abstract `AuthenticationAwareController` as base class for all your controllers in src/groovy and there have the convenience method like `user`

```
class AuthenticationAwareController {
    def authenticationService
    def getUser() { return authenticationService.loggedInUser() }
}
```

This way, you can later change you mind about storing the user however you like and don't have to change your code. Also you benefit from Caches in Hibernate, that share already retrieved user object instances between different sessions, so db roundtrips are avoided.

You still should check the retrieved user object for validity or throw an `AuthenticationException` in case the retrieval does not succeed. (Maybe something like `AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUser(failOnError = false)`.)

You can even make this Service/ControllerBase a small plugin an reuse that on every application or go directly with the spring security plugin... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this but is it really worth the trouble? It seems to me your only advantage is typing "user" instead of "request.user". Not a big gain. Anyway, I think you could follow the instructions in "12.7 Adding Dynamic Methods at Runtime" of the User Guide. I think that if you created a dynamic method "getUser() {return request.user}" that the Groovy JavaBeans getter/setter access would allow you to simply reference "user" the way you want.

If you do add a dynamic method you might want to skip the filter and do it all in the dynamic method.